# IPv6 SLAAC on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, network-manager, ipv6

I have a vserver with 16.04. with two 64 IPv6 subnets assigned.

I'm trying to get a random IPv6 address with SLAAC for communication with external servers.

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet dhcp
iface ens3 inet6 auto
```

However I do not get a IPv6 address.
This is the ouput of ip a `ip -6 a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1
   inet6 ::1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
   inet6 fe80::5054:a1ff:fe87:f16f/64 scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

I can add IPv6 addresses manually though with

```
sudo ip -6 addr add [NEW_ADDRESS]/64 dev ens3
```

Which gives me the following output of `ip -6` a and a working IPv6 address

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1
   inet6 ::1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
   inet6 [NEW_ADDRESS]/64 scope global valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 fe80::5054:a1ff:fe87:f16f/64 scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

This is the output of `sudo sysctl -a | grep net.ipv6.conf | grep -i ens3`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_dad = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_ra = 2
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_ra_defrtr = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_ra_from_local = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_ra_min_hop_limit = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_ra_mtu = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_ra_pinfo = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_ra_rtr_pref = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.autoconf = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.dad_transmits = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.force_mld_version = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.force_tllao = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.hop_limit = 64
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.ignore_routes_with_linkdown = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.max_desync_factor = 600
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.mldv1_unsolicited_report_interval = 10000
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.mldv2_unsolicited_report_interval = 1000
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.mtu = 1500
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.ndisc_notify = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.proxy_ndp = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.regen_max_retry = 3
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.router_probe_interval = 60
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.router_solicitation_delay = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.router_solicitation_interval = 4
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.router_solicitations = 3
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.suppress_frag_ndisc = 1
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.temp_prefered_lft = 86400
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.temp_valid_lft = 604800
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.use_oif_addrs_only = 0
net.ipv6.conf.ens3.use_tempaddr = 0
```

Comment: SLAAC works because the router (usually the default gateway) send out Router Advertisements (RAs) with the Autoconf flag set on a routed /64 prefix. Are you sure that the router is doing that?

Comment: How can I check for RAs? Is there another method to generate a random IPv6 without SLAAC?

Comment: You can check with tools like `wireshark` and `tcpdump`. You could write your own scripts to generate random addresses, but nothing as easy as SLAAC...

Comment: There are router advertisements (sorry for bad formatting):  
 `00:01:00.262677 IP6 (hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 24) fe80::1 > ip6-allnodes: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router advertisement, length 24  
 hop limit 64, Flags [none], pref medium, router lifetime 1800s, reachable time 0s, retrans time 0s
   source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): 00:00:5e:00:02:02
     0x0000:  0000 5e00 0202`

Comment: I don't see a network prefix in there, so there is nothing that SLAAC can use to configure addresses with. That is probably the problem

Comment: Is it possible to set the prefix manually or to send RAs (e.g. with radvd) for the same machine?

Comment: The _router_ needs to be fixed. Contact your provider.

Comment: To be fair, almost all vserver providers that I know (including the ones where I was involved in the deployment) intentionally disable SLAAC on their server networks to prevent servers unexpectedly getting random IPv6 addresses. Most machines on server networks are expected to be managed by the server admin, not by SLAAC. I think what you want is just not fitting in the provider's deployment strategy.